# How do I change the gamemode for my Team Fortress 2 server from capture the flag to payload?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

How can I change the game mode in tf2 server? in the server.cfg file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Change your server's startup map to a payload map and change the maps in your `mapcyclefile` (`tf/cfg/mapcycle.txt` by default) to payload maps.

Explanation:

For most game modes, it's the map that determines the game mode and not the server.

Payload maps all start with `pl_`.  The list of standard payload maps is stored in the server's `tf/cfg/mapcycle_quickplay_payload.txt`.  As of this writing, the list is:

```
pl_badwater
pl_frontier_final
pl_goldrush
pl_hoodoo_final
pl_thundermountain
pl_upward
pl_barnblitz
pl_borneo
```

There are also a small selection of Payload Race maps, where both teams have a cart:

```
plr_pipeline
plr_hightower
plr_nightfall_final
```

There are also a few Halloween-themed Payload and Payload Race maps:

```
plr_hightower_event
pl_millstone_event
```

and finally, a beta map that Valve is still working on:

```
pl_cactuscanyon
```

You can also use custom maps, including those from the [TF2 Map Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse/?appid=440&browsesort=trend&section=readytouseitems).  I even [wrote a guide for server owners](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=464901858) about it.

Note: I said *most* game modes earlier.  There are two exceptions:

### Mannpower

Mannpower uses specific CTF maps, but these CTF maps will be played as normal CTF maps unless you set these cvars:

```
tf_powerup_mode 1
tf_grapplinghook_enable 1
```

The CTF maps that are meant for use with Mannpower are:

```
ctf_foundry
ctf_gorge
ctf_thundermountain
ctf_hellfire
```

### Mann vs. Machine

While MvM does use the map's filename, MvM mode works differently than the other game modes.

- It will "crash" the server if `maxplayers` is set to something other than **32**.

  - MvM only allows 6 player characters and up to 4 spectators.  The other 16 slots are reserved for bots.
- As soon as you launch an MvM map, the server stops using the `mapcyclefile` (mapcycle.txt by default, TF2 looks in tf/cfg/ for this file).

  - Instead, MvM uses the `tf_mvm_missioncyclefile` (`tf_mvm_missioncycle.res` by default, TF2 looks in tf/ for this file) instead.  The default mission file is embedded `tf_misc_dir.vpk` and cannot be directly edited without extracting it first.

Comment: I just noticed my Map Workshop guide is out of date.  SourceMod 1.8 now directly supports Workshop maps in its plugins, including its MapChooser map vote plugin.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the server's startup map is set using `+map mapnamehere` on the command-line or in autoexec.cfg as `map mapnamehere`